# is this postgres regex expression equivalent to this like expression?

Tags: postgresql

This query returns no rows :

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.s ~ '^(N_|B_).*'
```

while this one does

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.s like 'N_%' or t.s like 'B_%';
```

Why are they not equivalent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An underscore character has special meaning in `LIKE`, for [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html):

> An underscore (_) in pattern stands for (matches) any single character; a percent sign (%) matches any sequence of zero or more characters. (...) To match a literal underscore or percent sign without matching other characters, the respective character in pattern must be preceded by the escape character.

So these queries are equivalent:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.s ~ '^(N_|B_).*';
SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.s like 'N\_%' or t.s like 'B\_%';
```